# How do I make a copy of a list in lower?

Tags: python, list

I need to do a copy of a list in lower, but I don't want to do it with a loop.
Something like this:

I try doing this:
`

```
new_users = ["moresede", "renerico", "antoniogr01", "darknight", "admin"]
new_users_lower = new_user[:].lower()
```

`

Comment: `new_users_lower  = [x.lower() for x in new_users]`

Comment: They are already lowercase. `[i.lower() for i in new_users]` ? `list(map(str.lower, new_users))` ?

Comment: `lower()` won't have any effect on those specific values...

Comment: @JohnGordon lol, but the unit tests pass fine!

Comment: @WillardSolutions that's why the TDD gurus tell you to write a failing test first.

Comment: The poster specified "don't want to do it with a loop". Is the "for" in comprehension considered to be a loop?

Comment: @user3435121 Technically yes. I added `map` solution but that is also a loop (in C).